# Hold apa_table position in Rmarkdown/papaja

Tags: latex, r-markdown, papaja

I do have another Rmarkdown/papaja package question from my side and would be very happy if anyone was willing to help :)

As many people on the internet I have trouble controlling the position of my tables.
I have the

```
floatsintext: yes
```

option included in the YAML header.
I know that there are LATEX options such as fig.pos = "!H" for which I have to load the float package

```
header-includes:
- usepackage\{float}
```

However, doing this I get the following error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option `H'.
```

Which tells me the float package was not able to load I guess?
(I do hav MacTex installed and also the newest R version).

What also is absolutely confusing to me is that tables (generated with app_table()) appear in the (approximately) right position when I leave the default spacing, but only appear at the end of my work when I add

```
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{setspace}
  - \AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\singlespacing}
  - \AtBeginEnvironment{lltable}{\singlespacing}
  - \AtBeginEnvironment{tablenotes}{\singlespacing}
```

to the YAML header in order to control the spacing of my tables.

I would really appreciate any help!
Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I don't know if this serves the purpose, but if I create the following options, my table appears at the end (and not where it should be)

```
title : "TITLE" 
shorttitle        : "short title"

author: 
  - name          : "me"
    affiliation   : "1"
    corresponding : yes    # Define only one corresponding author
    address       : "x"
    email         : "y"
    role:         # Contributorship roles (e.g., CRediT, https://casrai.org/credit/)
      - Conceptualization
      - Writing - Original Draft Preparation
      - Writing - Review & Editing
 #  - name          : "Ernst-August Doelle"
 #    affiliation   : "1,2"
 #    role:
  #      - Writing - Review & Editing

affiliation:
  - id            : "1"
    institution   : ""
 #  - id            : "2"
#     institution   : "Konstanz Business School"

authornote: |
  Enter author note here.

abstract:  |
 
keywords          : "keywords"
wordcount         : "X"

bibliography      : 

floatsintext      : yes
figurelist        : no
tablelist         : no
footnotelist      : no
linenumbers       : no
mask              : no
draft             : no

csl:                "apa.csl"
documentclass     : "apa7"
classoption       : "man"
output            : papaja::apa6_pdf

toc: true 
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{float}
  - \usepackage{setspace}
  - \AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\singlespacing}
  - \AtBeginEnvironment{lltable}{\singlespacing}
  - \AtBeginEnvironment{tablenotes}{\singlespacing}
---


{r setup, include = FALSE}
library("papaja")
library("apa")
library("tidyverse")
library("apaTables")
r_refs("r-references.bib")


{r analysis-preferences}
# Seed for random number generation
set.seed(42)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache.extra = knitr::rand_seed)


{r}
cor_table <- apa.cor.table(iris)


Text BLABLABLABLA

{r tab, results = "asis", fig.pos = "!h"}
apa_table(cor_table$table.body,
          caption = "Means, standard deviations, and correlations with confidence intervals for study variables.", 
          note = "Note. M and SD are used to represent mean and standard deviation, respectively.Values in square brackets indicate the 95% confidence interval.The confidence interval is a plausible range of population correlations that could have caused the sample correlation (Cumming, 2014). * indicates p < .05. ** indicates p < .01.", font_size = "footnotesize", row.names = F,
          placement = "p")


# Methods
We report how we determined our sample size, all data exclusions (if any), all manipulations, and all measures in the study. <!-- 21-word solution (Simmons, Nelson & Simonsohn, 2012; retrieved from http://ssrn.com/abstract=2160588) -->

## Participants

## Material

## Procedure

## Data analysis
We used `r cite_r("r-references.bib")` for all our analyses.


# Results

# Discussion


\newpage

# References

\begingroup
\setlength{\parindent}{-0.5in}
\setlength{\leftskip}{0.5in}

<div id="refs" custom-style="Bibliography"></div>
\endgroup
```

Comment: Can you make a [mre]?

Comment: I edited the post, sorry I don't know other ways to create a reproducible example.. I had to remove the ```signs before the R-chunks, so they must be added in the end.. Thanks for responding!

Comment: You can include ``` in your code if you use more backticks, e.g. ```` to embed the code block in your question.

Answer (score 2):

For PDF output, there is a recommended way to customize the placement of tables created via `apa_table()`. (You do not have to load the `float` package via header includes.)

First, set the YAML header option `floatsintext: yes`.

Second, when creating your table with `apa_table()`, use the function's `placement` argument:

````
```{r tab}
apa_table(cor_table$table.body,
          caption = "Means, standard deviations, and correlations with confidence intervals for study variables.", 
          note = "Note. M and SD are used to represent mean and standard deviation, respectively.Values in square brackets indicate the 95% confidence interval.The confidence interval is a plausible range of population correlations that could have caused the sample correlation (Cumming, 2014). * indicates p < .05. ** indicates p < .01.", font_size = "footnotesize", row.names = F,
          placement = "H")
````